# Enable autoconf IPv6 address on Raspbian

Tags: linux, networking, raspberry-pi, ipv6, raspbian

I have a Raspberry Pi, connected via Wi-Fi to my router (managed by my ISP), and I want to access it from the Internet. This router includes a firewall, which I would preferably keep active, with just a hole for certain ports on my Raspberry Pi. Sadly, it doesn't support access over UPnP, so I need a fixed address on my Raspberry Pi to configure the firewall manually.

I have connected the Raspberry Pi to Wi-Fi normally (via the GUI), but it only has a single globally routable IPv6 address, with a valid lifetime of one week and a preferred lifetime of one day. I'm assuming this is a privacy extensions address and that I will get a new one tomorrow. However, all sources on the Internet seem to say that I should also have a "normal" autoconf address (MAC with ff:fe in the middle). How do I enable this?

I'm on Raspbian 8.0 (jessie). /proc/sys/net/ipv6/conf/wlan0/autoconf is 0, which seems to be related to the problem. However, trying to override this in /etc/sysctl.conf doesn't work, it remains 0 after a reboot and reconnect to Wi-Fi.

Comment: Which address do you actually want?

Comment: I want the usual behaviour: a permanent address based on my MAC address and a temporary address that changes often and is used for outbound connections. The address it currently uses is still the same from yesterday though. So it seems to be somewhat stable but it still irks me that its lifetime is less than a day at all times and I have no idea what could trigger it to change.

Answer (score 1):

You also need net.ipv6.conf.wlan0.accept_ra=1.

I don't know why in recent Raspbian images they changed that parameter to 0 when it was 1 for years.

Comment: You can freely edit your own posts but for your protection, this must be done under the original user account.  It looks like you may have tried to edit the answer without logging into your account.

Answer (score 1):

To configure the address the EUI-64 way you require, enable the directive `slaac hwaddr` and disable `slaac private` directive in `/etc/dhcpcd.conf`:

```
#slaac private
slaac hwaddr
```

I've did some testing (***Raspbian Buster***) and even where I made persistent:

```
net.ipv6.conf.default.use_tempaddr=1
```

...in `/etc/sysctl.conf`, after rebooting the address configured is the EUI-64 format one using the MAC address with the `FF:FE` thingy in the middle. So looks like `/etc/dhcpcd.conf` settings are respected and the `sysctl` ones overridden.

Answer (score -1):

After a few days the IPv6 connection broke again.
Seems we need to edit /etc/dhcpcd.conf and replace "slaac private" by "slaac hardware".
Found this info here: https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=66&t=171508

For now it works.

Comment: This answer by itself does t answer the question.  Link didn't work for me

Comment: That’s funny; it works for me.  It doesn’t say much more than what’s in the answer above, so there’s no point in telling user694079 to include the essential parts of the answer here; he (or she?) has already done so.

Comment: Welcome to Super User. Are you and user692045 the same person?  If so, it would appear that you have accidentally created two accounts.  You should use the [contact form](//superuser.com/contact) and select “I need to merge user profiles” to have your accounts merged.  In order to merge them, you will need to provide links to the two accounts.  For your information, these are https://superuser.com/users/692045/user692045 and https://superuser.com/users/694079/user694079.  You’ll then be able to [edit] your answer(s).